# how to paste your sentence to the next one row using notepad++

Tags: keyboard, notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there a way to paste your line of code to the line under it without even copying it and by only using keyboard short-cut? 
I did it by mistake and I don't know how, I just think that it might be useful to know.

Comment: Something like Edit->Line Operations->Duplicate Current Line? In my Config that menu Item is bound to Ctrl-D.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctr+D . This will copy current line below it

Comment: This was already said in comment by @LarsFisher, that's not fair. You should answer as community wiki.